# Keeping Registrar's DNS Service but pointing to AWS Resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-amplify, amazon-route53

I have been struggling with this, I dont fully understand the concepts of DNS. But, all the articles I have come across details how to migrate from existing DNS Service to Route 53 DNS Service, which I have heard is not free. I just want a domain hosted at porkbun to point an Amplify app. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to connect your Porkbun domain to a third-party site(yourapp.amplifyapp.com), but AWS don't provide an IP address—but they do provide a (yourapp.amplifyapp.com).
No problem! You can do it: via CNAME flattening (aka ALIAS records).

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-a-third-party-dns-provider.html

Points 3,4,5 ... I can't add a domain unless I have a hosted zone...it does not mention that in the steps.

Comment: Sorry, I had to click Configure Domain first...It works...Thank you..

Comment: Instructions > https://kb.porkbun.com/article/85-how-to-connect-your-root-domain-when-your-web-host-wont-provide-an-ip-address